# To check if a list of numbers is arithmetic or geometric with python

Tags: python-3.x, math

Below is the code i have written which only check the 1st and the last patter and not in the middle. 
Any help is much appreciated.

```
def arith_geo(list_n):
    if len(list_n) == 0:
        return 0

    for n in range(len(list_n) - 1): 
        if (list_n[n + 1] - list_n[n]) == (list_n[n-1] - list_n[n-2]):
            return 'Arithmetic'
        elif (list_n[n + 1] / list_n[n]) == (list_n[n -1 ] / list_n[n - 2]):
            return 'Geometric'
        else:
            return -1
print(arith_geo([1, 2, 3, 8, 5, 6]))
```

Comment: your `for` loop , it will execute only single time because of `return` statement. What is the desire output needed? Is it your checking for series is in arithmetic progression or geometric progression?

Comment: @KalpeshDusane The desired output is as follow: For arithmetic progressions, return Arithmetic
For geometric progressions, return Geometric
For neither of the above, return -1
For an empty array, return 0

Answer (score 0):

1) Make special treatment for length 0,1,2  (is length 2 sequence valid AP or GP?)

2) Make `Arith_Counter` and `Geom_Counter` variables.

3) Make loop for indexes `n` in range `1..length-2`

4)  At every step.

```
  check if AP property valid - 
  if yes, increment Arith_Counter

  check if GP property valid 
  if yes, increment Geom_Counter.
```

5) At the end check that

```
Arith_Counter = length - 2
or
Geom_Counter = length - 2
(or both)
```

This is simple approach without early return (you can add checking counters after every step)

Comment: You might want to test that 7,7,7 gives both.

Comment: To do the suggestion of checking at every step, you could make the counters booleans and logically "and" Arith_Counter with itself and the test for the three terms you are considering. That way short circuit evaluation will keep you from testing an already failed sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MBo and @Jeremy Kahan, your answers were awesome directives and with them i managed to solve the question.
Here is what i have done:

```
 def arith_geo(list_n):
    if len(list_n) == 0:
        return 0
    diff = list_n[1] - list_n[0]
    div = list_n[1] / list_n[0]
    for num in range(1, len(list_n)):
        if list_n[num] - list_n[num - 1] == diff:
            counter = 'Arithmetic'
        elif list_n[num] / list_n[num-1] == div:
            counter = 'Geometric'
        else:
            counter = -1
            break
    return counter
print(arith_geo([2,4,8,16]))
print(arith_geo([1,2,3,4]))
print(arith_geo([1,2,8,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `all` built-in function and sequential elimination of possible states it could be implemented pretty straightforward:

```
def arith_geo(list_n):

    if len(list_n) < 2:
        return "Not a progression - the list is too short"

    # ---------------------------------------------
    states = ['Arithmetic', 'Geometric'] # possible states of list_n

    b1, b2 = list_n[:2]
    adj_elements = list(zip(list_n[1:], list_n[2:]))

    # ---------------------------------------------
    # arithmetric part:
    # ---------------------------------------------

    if not all(y - x == b2 - b1 for x,y in adj_elements):
        states.remove('Arithmetic')

    # ---------------------------------------------
    # geometric part:
    # ---------------------------------------------
    # according to the definition of geometric progression:
    # b1 != 0
    # q != 0 <=> b2 != 0
    # ---------------------------------------------

    if b1 * b2 == 0 or not all(y / x == b2 / b1 for x,y in adj_elements):
        states.remove('Geometric')

    # ---------------------------------------------
    state_message = {0:"Neither arithmetic nor geometric", 
                     2:"Both arithmetic and geometric", 
                     1:(states+[''])[0]}

    return state_message[len(states)]
```

Results:

```
print(arith_geo([])) # Not a progression - the list is too short
print(arith_geo([0])) # Not a progression - the list is too short

print(arith_geo([1, 2])) # Both arithmetic and geometric
print(arith_geo([7, 7])) # Both arithmetic and geometric
print(arith_geo([7, 7, 7])) # Both arithmetic and geometric

print(arith_geo([0, 0])) # Arithmetic
print(arith_geo([0, 1])) # Arithmetic
print(arith_geo([1, 0])) # Arithmetic
print(arith_geo([0, 2, 4])) # Arithmetic
print(arith_geo([7, 5, 3])) # Arithmetic

print(arith_geo([1, 2, 4])) # Geometric
print(arith_geo([1, -0.5, 0.25])) # Geometric

print(arith_geo([0, 2, 3, 8])) # Neither arithmetic nor geometric
print(arith_geo([1, 2, 3, 8])) # Neither arithmetic nor geometric
```

Note that the function distinguishes between pairs `[0, 0]` and `[7, 7]`, as well as `[0, 1]` and `[1, 2]` - according to the definition of geometric progression.

Comment: @SPSP, the output is "Geometric". What did you get?

Comment: it should be geometric

Comment: @SPSP, indeed. So, did you get the output which differs from "Geometric"?

Comment: with your code the output says `Neither arithmetic nor geometric`

Comment: it is because of the euclide division, you should parse x or y to float

Comment: @SPSP, it's because you use Python 2x. While the tag `python-3x` from the question clearly says that a solution is required for Python 3x. In Python 3  for the input list `[4, -2, 1, -0.5, 0.25]` my code produces "Geometric"